# Scaling a TikZ figure from an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, external-files

I would like to insert figures which were created with TikZ to my LaTeX document.

I suppose that if I create the TikZ figure inside the document, that wouldn't be a problem - I'd just play with the `scale` value which comes right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. However, sometimes the figure is too complicated for it to be written explicitly in the LaTeX document, so I create the figure in a different file and use `\input{foo.tikz}`. The problem with that is that I don't see how to scale it to fit the rest of the document.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can set the `every picture` locally in a group around the input file to set any option which should be used for the `tikzpicture` in that file.

```
\begingroup
\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3}}%
\input{sometikzpic}%
\endgroup
```

However, if you have other `tikzpicture`s inside nodes of the main picture they will also be affected (twice I mean). In this case, `\tikzset{every picture/.style={scale=0.3,every picture/.style={}}}` might work better.

---

Note that `scale` scales only coordinates. Text is not affected. You might want to scale the whole picture all together. For this use `\scalebox{<factor>}{\input{<file>}}` or
`\resizebox{<width>}{!}{\input{<file>}}`. This both macros come from `graphics` which is loaded already by `tikz`.

Also have a look at the `standalone` class, especially the new `\includestandalone[<options>]{<file>}` from v1.0beta which will include subfiles and scales them if requested, like `\includegraphics` does for images.

Comment: I actually much prefer this solution to mine. It can be used without modifying the tikz file. Will this override an explicitly set scale in the included file? Presumably not…

Comment: @Seamus: AFAIK, the `every picture` style is executed before the optional settings. So you will end up with two `scale` settings. I think both are then applied, i.e. multiplied which each other.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!
Perhaps it's possible to scale it such as it fits the page's width?

Comment: @Shmuel: `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\input{<file>}}` or `\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{<file>}` with `standalone` v1.0beta1

Comment: absolutely no effect

Comment: @ODIUM: This answer is from 2011, so TikZ versions from 2020+ might behave differently now. Try my suggested code in my previous comment.

Answer (score 9):

If inside `foo.tex` you set the scale to `\tkzscl` or some other user macro, you can then set it like so:

```
\def\tkzscl{0.3}
\input{foo}
```

This way, you can set the scale of the picture in the main file.

`foo.tex` should then look like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\tkzscl]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Or whatever…

Answer (score 9):

I know this has been answered, so here's a little trick to use these answers.

-1- Put this after your `\usepackages` and before your `\begin{document}`:

```
\newcommand{\inputTikZ}[2]{%  
     \scalebox{#1}{\input{#2}}  
}
```

-2- Use it like this to create a figure:

```
\begin{figure}  
\begin{centering}  
    \inputTikZ{0.5}{mytikzfile.tkz}  
\end{centering}  
\label{fig:myFig}  
\caption{some caption for the figure}  
\end{figure}
```

In this way, the syntax is similar to `\includegraphics[scale=...]{filename}`

Comment: instead of using the environment `centering` (which I do not know existed), use the command `\centering` and remove the enviroment. See [center vs. centering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

Comment: upvoted for usage of scalebox!

Comment: @zeroth agreed ! Using `\begin{centering} \end{centering}` doesn't center properly, whereas `\centering` does.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you should use the `tikzscale` package. Supposing your complicated tikz picture is in the file `drawing.tikz`, you could do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{drawing.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red,thick,dashed] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\draw (1,1) node[below] {$a+b^2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{drawing.tikz}
        \caption{A nice drawing.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The same approach also works for related packages, for instance `tikz-3dplot`, or plots drawn with `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{plot.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={Something },
    xlabel={Something else},
]

\addplot[red,thick,domain=-2:2,samples=100] {exp(-x)+4*sin(deg(x))-x^2};
\addplot[blue,ultra thick,domain=-2:2,samples=100] {2*cos(deg(x))+x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=60mm]{plot.tikz}
        \caption{A nice plot.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the style presented by fiacobelli's answer.

On Preamble insert the packages

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

My advice is to create a new command

```
\newcommand{\figTikzAdjustShortCap}[4]
{   
    \centering
    \adjustbox{#1}{\input{#2}}
    \caption[#4]{#3}
}
```

You may create variations changing the "adjustbox" line to:

```
\resizebox{#1\linewidth}{#2\linewidth}{\input{#3}}
```

or

```
\scalebox{#1}{\input{#2}}
```

remembering to correct the number of inputs of the \newcommand.

This follow the same standard I use for includegraphics:

```
\newcommand{\figIncLongCap}[3]
{   
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
}
```

I like it because let me change the caption position of all figure in a single move.

And you may use it inside Figure environment, where "Fig_Tikz" is a .tex file.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \figTikzAdjustLongCap
    {width = 0.8\linewidth, keepaspectratio, trim = 1.5cm 2cm 3cm 0cm, clip = true}
    {Fig_Tikz}
    {Tikz with \textit{AdjustBox} and \textit{Trim} Caption}
    \label{Fig_Tikz}
\end{figure}
```

This results gives you the same structure of a includegraphic command:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \figIncLongCap
    {width = 0.5\linewidth, trim = 0cm 1cm 0cm 0cm, clip = true}
    {Fig_not_tikz}
    {Fig not Tikz Caption.}
    \label{Fig_not_tikz}
\end{figure}
```

This option let us work and format a \input exactly like a \includegraphic.

I prefer to use the figure environment because of the label highlight and "click and found" features of TexStudio and others LaTeX editors.

Answer (score 1):

When using `\input` to import a figure consisting of a PGFPlots axis, I found that

```
\begingroup
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale=2}}
\input{tikzfig}
\endgroup
```

was the best solution to scale only the axes without changing nor the ticks nor the axes labels font.