# TikZ: the scale option changes font size

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, scaling

When I use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=X]` with `X<1/X>1` then font size of text in the picture is also changed. I need to use `[scale=2]` or `[scale=0.5]` and to preserve font size (e.g. `normalsize`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}}

\begin{document}
 Short text with normal size font.

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, font=\normalsize]
  \begin{axis}
   [
    ymin=0,ymax=12,xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ylabel={frequency},xlabel={group},
    xtick=data,xticklabels={A,B},
    ytick={0,10},
   ]

   \addplot plot coordinates
   {
    (1,10)
    (2,6)
   };
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

  Another short text with normal size font.

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, font=\normalsize]
  \begin{axis}
   [
    ymin=0,ymax=12,xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ylabel={frequency},xlabel={group},
    xtick=data,xticklabels={A,B},
    ytick={0,10},
   ]

   \addplot plot coordinates
   {
    (1,10)
    (2,6)
   };
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image: and here is result from my TeXstudio 2.6.0 under Win7]

Comment: If your `tikzpicture` only contains a PGFPlots axis, you can move the `scale=2` to the `axis` options: That way, the font sizes aren't affected.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be very simple solution. It is strange that I found out only opposite problem = how to change by "scale" also font size.

Answer (score 11):

If your tikzpicture only contains a PGFPlots axis, you can move the `scale=2` to the axis options: that way, the font sizes aren't affected.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}}

\begin{document}
 Short text with normal size font.

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   [
    scale=2,
    ymin=0,ymax=12,xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ylabel={frequency},xlabel={group},
    xtick=data,xticklabels={A,B},
    ytick={0,10},
   ]

   \addplot plot coordinates
   {
    (1,10)
    (2,6)
   };
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

  Another short text with normal size font.

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   [
    ymin=0,ymax=12,xmin=0,xmax=3,
    ylabel={frequency},xlabel={group},
    xtick=data,xticklabels={A,B},
    ytick={0,10},
    scale=0.5
   ]

   \addplot plot coordinates
   {
    (1,10)
    (2,6)
   };
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38605/scaling-a-tikz-figure-from-an-external-file/73610), you can set this property when using `\input{}` in case you generate your figure in an externate file.
The following did the trick for me :

```
\begingroup
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.style={scale=2}}
\input{tikzfig}
\endgroup
```

Using :

```
\tikzset{every axis/.style={scale=2}}
```

would also be possible but generates a warning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!